# LWC Tree grid ontoggle action triggers onrowselection

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightningtreegrid

This is how I am using treegrid component.

When I expand a treegrid row, and then collapse it, automatically onrowselection event is fired, which calls onRowSelection action handler in JS controller and unchecked my child automatically because of the onrowSelection called .how do i remove this ? what i am missing . please help me.

I found something here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g8g4QAA
Please some one help me to convert this to LWC. I dont know Aura component

```
 <lightning-tree-grid  key-field="id" 
                    show-checkbox-column 
                    data-id="grid"
                    expanded-rows={gridExpandedRows}
                    ontoggle={handleToggle}
                    onrowselection={setSelectedRows}
                    selected-rows={selectedrows}
                    ></lightning-tree-grid>
```

handleMethod.js

```
            handleToggle(ev){
        
              this.bypassrowselection = ev.detail.isExpanded;
            }
            
        setSelectedRows(event)
          {
            
            if(this.bypassrowselection) {
              return;
          }
        
            var selectRows =this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree-grid').getSelectedRows();
             
            
              if(selectRows.length > 0){
                var templist = [];
                  selectRows.forEach(function (record){
                    
                    templist.push(record.id);
                  })
                  
                  this.dataObj.forEach(element => {
                     
                      element.items && element.items.forEach(record => {
                       
                     
                      if(!this.currentSelectedRows.includes(record.id) && templist.includes(record.id)) {
                        record.items.forEach(function (item){
                                           
                                              templist.push(item.id);
                                             })
                      }
                     
                     
                     
                      if(this.currentSelectedRows.includes(record.id) && !templist.includes(record.id)) {
                          record.items.forEach(item => {
                          
                              const index = templist.indexOf(item.id);
                              if(index > -1) {
                                templist.splice(index, 1);
                              }
                          })
                      }
                      
                      var allSelected = true;
                      record.items && record.items.forEach(item => {
                          if(!templist.includes(item.id)) {
                              allSelected = false;
                          }
                      })
                      
                      if(allSelected && !templist.includes(record.id)) {
                        
                        templist.push(record.id);
                      } else if(!allSelected && templist.includes(record.id)) {
                          const index = templist.indexOf(record.id);
                          if(index > -1) {
                            templist.splice(index, 1);
                          }
                      }
        
                  })
                  
                  
                })
                  
                  this.selectedrows = templist;
                 this.currentSelectedRows = templist;
               
                }    
             
                  
            
          }
```

Comment: here's similar discussion https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8cazSAB

Comment: @AmanPatil  I found something here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g8g4QAA
Please some one help me to convert this to LWC. I dont know Aura component

Comment: what do you need to convert ?

Comment: @AmanPatil Please read this . i couldnt understand aura. is this resolve my problem
 developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000g8g4QAA  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the link that you provided and tried my best to convert in LWC

Html

```
<template>
    <lightning-tree-grid columns={gridColumns}
                         data={gridData}
                         expanded-rows={gridExpandedRows}
                         key-field="Id"
                         selected-rows={selectedRows}
                         onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                         ontoggle={handleRowToggle}
                         ontoggleall={handleRowToggle}>
    </lightning-tree-grid>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class MyTreeGrid extends LightningElement {
    @api gridColumns;
    @api gridData;
    @track gridExpandedRows;
    @track selectedRows;
    @track selectedRowsStored;
    @track bypassOnRowSelection = false;
    @track expandedRowsCount = 0;

    handleRowSelection(event) {
        if (!this.bypassOnRowSelection) {
            this.selectedRowsStored = event.detail.selectedRows;
        }
        this.bypassOnRowSelection = false;
    }

    handleRowToggle(event) {
        const treeGridComponent = this.template.querySelector('lightning-tree-grid');
        if (treeGridComponent) {
            const currentExpandedRows = treeGridComponent.getCurrentExpandedRows();
            if (currentExpandedRows && currentExpandedRows.length !== null && currentExpandedRows.length !== undefined) {
                if (currentExpandedRows.length >= this.expandedRowsCount) {
                    const selectedRowsStoredIds = [];
                    const selectedRowsStored = this.selectedRowsStored;
                    if (selectedRowsStored && selectedRowsStored.length > 0) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < selectedRowsStored.length; i++) {
                            selectedRowsStoredIds.push(selectedRowsStored[i].Id);
                        }
                    }
                    this.selectedRows = selectedRowsStoredIds;
                } else {
                    this.bypassOnRowSelection = true;
                }
                this.expandedRowsCount = currentExpandedRows.length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: really thanks. but it didnt help

Comment: Can you try this in your `handleToggle`method  `this.bypassrowselection = ev.detail.isExpanded;
  if (!ev.detail.isExpanded) {
    // Reset the bypassrowselection variable when a row is collapsed
    this.bypassrowselection = false;
  }`

Comment: i tried this. not working.